# How to test Apple Watch Actionable Notifications in Watch Simulator?

Tags: ios9, xcode7, apple-watch, watch-notification

I am working on apple watch app & implementing actionable notifications.Can we test these notifications on a watch simulator rather than testing them on real device?

Comment: please try in real device.

Comment: i don't have apple watch device..thats why i am facing this issue..

Comment: but simulator is not supported. please read Apple Watch Guidelines.

Comment: ya..i got that..thanks for reply

Comment: okay. if u agree then accept my ans. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No actionable notifications require a device token, which is not available on the simulator.

You will receive this message: "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator"

You need to test on device, to test Push Notifications.

You can use this library to simulate remote notifications though: https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications

> If your iOS app supports local or remote notifications, Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times. When one of your app’s local or remote notification arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on Apple Watch.